# Unable to login to iMac after successful ARD/VNC connection

Tags: network, unix, ssh, remote-desktop, apple-remote-desktop

I enabled Apple Remote Desktop on an iMac, and I'm trying to use it from a Ubuntu machine with Remmina Remote Desktop Client. I configured the connection to use SSH tunneling.

1. I can connect successfully to the mac over the Internet;
2. The login screen of the Mac is displayed;
3. I enter my password on the normal mac login screen;
4. Password prompt blinks lightly but no error is displayed (it is as if the password was incorrect) and the session is not started.

Is this a known problem, any solution?

- I am able to establish the remote connection (the mac login screen is displayed).
- **Problem is I cannot login afterwards.** I know password is correct (the VNC client asks for username/password to establish the SSH tunnel).